# Solve the socket.gai error - Name or service not known

Tags: python

I created a code for port scanning that raises an error that says `socket.gaierror:[Errno -2] Name or service not known`.

This error is specified on a line that goes like;

```
if socket.connect_ex((host,port)):
```

[image]

Comment: Did you know that you can create so called "screenshots"?

Comment: The error says your `host` variable is not valid

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that DNS can resolve the host you are attempting to scan.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: well i can't comment so making an answer was the only way to interact